# Qt Creator C++ error: No documents matching "ui_mainwindow.h" could be found

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I'm currently using Qt Creator 4.15.2. I tried creating a new project in the creator, the .h, .cpp, and .ui files are perfectly linked. If I changed anything in the creator, everything is synchronized. When I selected action->Go to slot, it immediately finds everything.

Then I copied the mainwindow.cpp, mainwindow.h and mainwindow.ui files to my own C++ project. My project has lots of other dependencies so it's hard to create this project directly in the creator. I have successfully included QT5 in my project, so, if I don't use the creator but adding everything manually, everything works fine.

I added the UI file to my CMake list, then opened the UI file in Qt creator. When I changed anything in the creator, the UI file is synchronized and the ui_mainwindow.h file is generated. The problem then comes, if I click action->Go to slot, this error pops up:

> No documents matching "ui_mainwindow.h" could be found. Rebuilding the
> project might help.

I have tried every method online but none of them worked. Now if I want to include the actions, I have to manually add them in the ui_mainwindow.h file (in this way, it wouldn't automatically add the actions) or mainwindow.h file, which is tedious. Does anyone have an idea of how this could be solved?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with these steps:

- In my CMakesLists.txt I addded `set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)`
- Right-click on the project, then select "Run CMake"
- Rebuild the project
- If it doesn't work - restart QtCreator - that helped in my case (QtCreator 4.15.0)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a path directory error. when your auto-generated ui_mainwindow file is not placed in the desired place
also, you can open your UI file with qt designer and from "form -> view source " action menu see the final ui_mainwindow file contents and manually create a ui_mainwindow in your new project.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. But I couldn' t find this form-view source action in qt creator. Do I need to use qt designer studio instead? On the other hand, I could find the auto-generated file ui file in my project. It's just that none of the actions can be auto-generated. Do you mean that I always need to manually copy the ui_mainwindow.h contents to my new project?

Comment: yes, you can see view source action in the qt-designer application, not qt-creator->designMode.
absolutely no. qt5_wrap_ui command creates your UI files and simply you can access auto-generated UI files. but if you can not share your project and still have the problem, can manually fix this problem .

Comment: or you can use CMAKE_AUTOUIC, somethings like this repository :
https://github.com/jasondegraw/Qt-CMake-HelloWorld